# Redirect 404 error with public_html subfolder as a root folder for website

Tags: .htaccess

I used to run a Wordpress website, but started building my own in php. I was building it on a subdirectory on my server and now want to launch the new website. The structure is as follows:

public_html/newversion/index.php

public_html/newversion/category.php

public_html/newversion/category/information.php

I've edited the .htaccess file in public_html to force non-www and https, set newversion as the new document root, and some code to remove the .php extension from URLs (see the .htaccess code below).

That means that I want newversion/index.php to show up when someone goes to example.com, instead of the person needing to go to example.com/newversion/index.php.

Everything works fine, except when I try to access category.php or information.php. Then the browser is automatically redirected to example.com/newversion/category.php and I get a 404 error. When I try to access information.php, the browser tries to open example.com/category/information.php, but I also get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?
(FYI, Wordpress is not installed anymore)

```
    # Apache Rewrite Rules
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Base Redirects #

    # Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

    # Include trailing slash on directory 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

    # Force HTTPS and remove WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
    RewriteCond %{https} off  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Change root folder to subfolder of public_html
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newversion%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newversion%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/newversion%{REQUEST_URI} -l 
    RewriteRule ^ /newversion%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

    # Set php version
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-recommended-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3

    </IfModule>

    # Restrict access
    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a long time figuring this out, but I now know what people mean with .htaccess Rewrite voodoo... So, for anyone still needing an answer:

In the end, the order in which you declare htaccess rules and the subdirectory in which you do it matters a lot. Don't ask me how it works exactly, because I don't fully understand. However, this code worked for me.

The underlying code achieves the following:

- website root in subdirectory
- force non-www and https
- remove .php extension from url
- open subdirectories as example.com/foo/ whether or not entered with trailing slash
- open files in subdirectories as example.com/foo/bar whether or not entered with a trailing slash

.htaccess file in public_html:

```
# htaccess for public_html

Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Remove www and force https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# add a trailing slash if public/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdirectory/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

#Prevent direct access to PHP Scripts
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ subdirectory/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!subdirectory/).*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Then in the subdirectory add the following htaccess file:

```
# htaccess for subdirectory

# Remove trailing slashes (keep as first rule!)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# Open page without php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```